# youtube video not starting in ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, video, iframe, youtube

I hope you could help me.

I have created an app with ionic-v4 that uses iframe for showing some videos from youtube.

Every video works for android, while in ios every video but 3 are played correctly.

The iframe loads correctly the preview of the video, but when I click on play, it says video unavailable. Just three videos on 25.

We have tried to remove those 3 videos from youtube and the to resubmit them on the tube, yesterday night it worked, now they don’t work again.

What can be happened? Something about permissions or similar?

These are the videos that are not playing in ios

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SRvoELJDw8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj2KWJevFSI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxuv_zp5Fhs

and this is an example of video that is played correctly in ios

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieL7Bzcu9Ow

And this is the code I use:

html:

(item.linkYoutube is the id of the youtube video, i.g. 5SRvoELJDw8 for the first video i posted)

```
<iframe width="100%" height="250" [src]="getLinkYouTubeEmbedded(item.linkYoutube) | safe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

ts:

```
getLinkYouTubeEmbedded(x: string): string { return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + x; }
```

pipe safe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from ‘@angular/core’;
import { DomSanitizer } from ‘@angular/platform-browser’;

@Pipe({
name: ‘safe’
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
transform(url) {
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a way you can check the details beyond `video unavailable`? - I see the *unavailable* videos came from the same channel. Are you the admin of the channel? if so, check he channel settings.

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same channel. I don't know how to check details beyond video unavailable, i'm checking channel setting but i don't see nothing of strange, all video have the same settings.

Comment: Maybe is the code itself. Can you add a log and test again? - mayeb the URL you got of `getLinkYouTubeEmbedded` function has something else added and hence, shows an invalid video (*so to speak*) - research also similar problem to yours in Stack Overflow and in Google - I honestly don't know exact, but, when the code works in an mobile and not in other, the problem is some native from that specific version of the mobile. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does it work if set directly?... `[src]="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5SRvoELJDw8"`

Comment: Well, I fixed. The problem was that the three videos had music copyright problems, but It was signed Just as warning in YouTube studio. I have substituted audio in videos, and the problem disappeared. So, I believe that Android gives no importance to It, while iOS Is more severe in that. Thank you all!